# How long have you stayed or How long have you been staying

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Are both the present perfect and the present perfect progressive correct in the following? If so, what's the difference?

I prefer the present perfect progressive because the stay seems to be going on. But is the present perfect possible?

> A: How long have you stayed in New York? / How long have you been staying in New York?

> B: I've been here for seven days. I visited many tourist spots.

Comment: It might be an idea if you said IN the question what you know about the Present Perfect and the Present Perfect Continuous tenses. It would save effort and time for anyone who was thinking of posting an answer.

Comment: Yes, both tenses can be used for unfinished or ongoing actions: *I've known him for years.*

Comment: How long have you stayed in New York? may be correct but it does not sound it. Normally you would say  How long have you been in New York? the same as you have said in your reply "I've been here for seven days"

Comment: @Brad Does the present perfect progressive version sound natural to you?

Comment: @Apollyon yes it does sound OK. However in reality if you all know where or what you talking about (which is usual if it is still happening) very often you would drop the full name. "How long have you been staying here?" meaning in New York. Once again, as you did in your reply.

Answer (score 1):

### Both constructions would be correct

The reason is that when you use stative verbs in the present perfect it is understood to also be in the present perfect progressive. I have given this explanation in another [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252014/has-felt-has-been-feeling-why-is-the-first-wrong-here/280521#280521).

These two sentences have the essentially same meaning:

> I have been here for 7 days.

> I have been staying here for 7 days.

### Stay vs. be somewhere

When you say "I have been staying here", it would have to mean a place where you can stay temporarily. Likewise, the question, "How long have you been staying here?" would sound awkward unless you were referring to a place you're renting, like a hotel or rented apartment.

### Can't use be in the continuous/progressive

Just like you can't say:

> I am being here for 7 days.

You can't say:

> I have been being here for 7 days.

Therefore one would say:

> I have been here for 7 days.